# Tensor product criteria of an extension separability

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, tensor-products, separable-extension

> Given an extension $L|\mathbb{k}$ I need to prove that the ring $L\otimes_{\mathbb{k}}L$ embeds into a direct product of algebraic extensions of $L$ if and only if $L|\mathbb{k}$ is separable.

I can prove that separability of $L|\mathbb{k}$ entails that $L\otimes_{\mathbb{k}}L$ doesn’t have nilpotent elements. This is due to the fact that for any element $\alpha\in L$ and its minimal polynomial $f_{\alpha}\in \mathbb{k}[X]$ we now that $L[X]/(f_{\alpha})\hookrightarrow L\otimes_{\mathbb{k}} L$. Thus, if $\alpha$ is inseparable then $L(X)/f_{\alpha}$ is not reduced.

However I stuck here. Also i’m not sure if the notion of algebraic extension here is necessary.  I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: A product of algebraic extensions of $L$ is reduced, so you get the “only if”. For the “if”, there are a few possible routes, but they depend on what you’re already familiar with.

Comment: @Aphelli So the notion of algebraic field is indeed necessary?  I’m already familiar with some standard constructions in Galois theory and some very basic statements of algebraic number theory.

Comment: What do you mean by “algebraic field”? Do you mean algebraic field *extension*? This is probably not necessary if you’re used to working with finite field extensions and $L/k$ is finite.

Comment: Yes, i’m referring to the specification that it embeds to a direct product of algebraic field extensions